# Scripts on another page are not getting included while loading it in div using w3-include-html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is the script for w3-include-html:

```
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
```

This is my `div` tag where another page needs to get loaded:

```
<div w3-include-html="today.html">
    <script>
    w3IncludeHTML();
    </script>
</div>
```

This is my page `today.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
   <table border="2">
      <tr>
         <th>School</th>
         <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
      <script>
      for(var i=0;i<8;i++) {
        var ses="one";
        var time="time";
        document.write("<tr><td><a href='"+ses+"'>"+ses+"</a></td>"+
                    "<td>"+time+"</td></tr>");
      }
      </script>
   </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

When the page loads I get the output as:

[image: div output]

The scripts on another page are not working with w3-include-html whereas when I run `today.html` individually it is working:

[image: today.html]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not mentioned proper path of your scripts in your `<div>` tag so Try this:

```
<div w3-include-html="today.html">
    <script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the Body tag of the main HTML you should add following.

```
<script src="assets/js/w3data.js"></script>
<script>w3IncludeHTML();</script>
```

And then you need replace your today.html for following

```
<table border="2">
      <tr>
         <th>School</th>
         <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
      <script>
      for(var i=0;i<8;i++) {
        var ses="one";
        var time="time";
        document.write("<tr><td><a href='"+ses+"'>"+ses+"</a></td>"+
                    "<td>"+time+"</td></tr>");
      }
      </script>
   </table>
```

I think it's simple.

Don't include w3IncludeHTML(); into your replacement div.